# Insert/Update data to SQL Server table on specific time of the day

Tags: asp.net, datetime, global-variables, insert-update, job-scheduling

I have a about 10 application variable counters in `Global.asax` for displaying the file downloads of these different 10 categories. Now I want to insert/Update values of these counters on a specific time (due to reset of counter when application restart get reset the counter) say at 11PM each day and update the counter.

How to do? Any ideas?

In `Global.asax`:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
        Application.Add("MGM",0); 
        Application.Add("PC",0); 
        Application.Add("NC",0); 
        Application.Add("TC",0); 
        Application.Add("PGC",0); 
}
```

The `shortCode` parameter is the name of global session from `Global.asax` file. That I am passing to get the counter and increment accordingly.

In `Download.aspx.cs` page:

```
private int GetCount(string shordCode) 
{ 
    int count=0; 
    count = Convert.ToInt32(Application[shortCode]); 

    lock (Application[shortCode]) 
    { 
        Application[shortCode] = ++count; 
    } 

    return count; 
}
```

Help appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use below code.

```
public void GetCurrentTime()
    {
        int hours ;
        hours = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours;
        //when time is 23Hrs of the day
        if (hours == 23)
        {
//       UpdateCounter here           
        }
    }
```